# Unable to use libraries from OPM (OpenResty)

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty, luajit

I'm new to OpenResty, and I was trying to use the [lua-resty-radixtree](https://github.com/api7/lua-resty-radixtree) library, and I am running into an error:

```bash
Hello User!
ERROR: /usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/resty/radixtree.lua:102: /usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/librestyradixtree.so
/usr/local/openresty/lualib/librestyradixtree.so
./librestyradixtree.so
/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/librestyradixtree.so
/usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib/lua/5.1/librestyradixtree.so
/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/librestyradixtree.so
tried above paths but can not load librestyradixtree.so
stack traceback:
        /usr/local/openresty/site/lualib/resty/radixtree.lua:102: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        lua/hello.lua:3: in function 'file_gen'
        init_worker_by_lua:45: in function <init_worker_by_lua:43>
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
        init_worker_by_lua:52: in function <init_worker_by_lua:50>
```

Here is the Lua code:

```lua
ngx.say("Hello User!")

local radix = require("resty.radixtree")
        local rx = radix.new({
            {
                paths = {"/aa", "/bb*", "/name/:name/*other"},
                hosts = {"*.bar.com", "foo.com"},
                methods = {"GET", "POST", "PUT"},
                remote_addrs = {"127.0.0.1","192.168.0.0/16",
                                "::1", "fe80::/32"},
                vars = {
                    {"arg_name", "==", "json"},
                    {"arg_weight", ">", 10},
                },
                filter_fun = function(vars, opts)
                    return vars["arg_name"] == "json"
                end,

                metadata = "metadata /bb",
            }
        })

        -- try to match
        local opts = {
            host = "foo.com",
            method = "GET",
            remote_addr = "127.0.0.1",
            vars = ngx.var,
        }
        ngx.say(rx:match("/aa", opts))

        -- try to match and store the cached value
        local opts = {
            host = "foo.com",
            method = "GET",
            remote_addr = "127.0.0.1",
            vars = ngx.var,
            matched = {}
        }
        ngx.say(rx:match("/name/json/foo/bar/gloo", opts))
        ngx.say("name: ", opts.matched.name, " other: ", opts.matched.other)
```

And the Nginx configuration:

```
pid logs/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 8080;
    location / {
      content_by_lua_file lua/hello.lua;
      }
    }
  }
```

I had installed the libraries through OPM by running:

```bash
sudo opm get xiangnanscu/lua-resty-radixtree
sudo opm get xiangnanscu/lua-resty-expr
sudo opm get xiangnanscu/lua-resty-ipmatcher
```

Looking into the issue, I found that OpenResty is under this path `/usr/bin/openresty` while the Lua library is searching for the `.so` file in the `/usr/local/openresty` folder as shown in the error.

I tried setting this in the `nginx.conf` file but it did not change anything:

```
lua_package_path "$prefix/resty_modules/lualib/?.lua;;";
lua_package_cpath "$prefix/resty_modules/lualib/?.so;;";
```

Any idea what the issue is and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`xiangnanscu/lua-resty-radixtree`](https://opm.openresty.org/package/xiangnanscu/lua-resty-radixtree/) package you are trying to use is *not official* (it's originated from [this fork](https://github.com/xiangnanscu/lua-resty-radixtree)) and does not indeed contain the `librestyradixtree.so`.

Moreover, `opm` does not support native shared libraries (`.so`/`.dll`/`.dylib`) whatsoever:

> `opm` currently only supports pure Lua libraries

Check [the documentation](https://opm.openresty.org/docs#description).

You should probably follow the official installation instructions — https://github.com/api7/lua-resty-radixtree#install

---

FWIW: the error you've got is raised [here](https://github.com/api7/lua-resty-radixtree/blob/v2.8.2/lib/resty/radixtree.lua#L92-L103).

Comment: Thanks. After installing LuaRocks and the original library from it, it seems to work. But now I'm running into a different issue that says "API disabled in the current context."